# Dynamically creating a cumulative list having a limit

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5

I want to create a cumulative list having a limit on generated function f as shown below, is there any python-3 construct or a pythonic way, which I can use to accelerate this?

```
import numpy as np
f = lambda x: 2**x
events = []
limit = 10
i = 0
while(True):
    if np.sum(events)+f(i)<=10:
        events.append(f(i))
    else:
        break
    i += 1

print(np.cumsum(events))
```

Output:

```
[1 3 7]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cumulative sum of `2**i` series is fairly easy to compute:

```
>>> np.cumsum([2**i for i in range(100) if 2**(i+1) < limit - 1])
array([1, 3, 7])
```

For an arbitrary function `f`, I'd simply filter the result:

```
x = np.cumsum([f(i) for i in range(100)])
result = x[x < limit]
```

**Update:**

The same for unlimited generators using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < limit, (2**(i+1)-1 for i in itertools.count())))
[1, 3, 7]
```

Arbitrary `f` function requires few additional lines to accumulate the sum:

```
cum_sum = [0]
def update(cum_sum, val): cum_sum[0] += val; return cum_sum[0]
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < limit, (update(cum_sum, f(i)) for i in itertools.count())))
```

Comment: you are assuming the max limit of i to be 100 but in the real case that is not know